# Pass parameter to npm script and then gulp-task

Tags: npm, gulp

is it somehow possible to pass a parameter to a npm script which calls a gulp task and passes on the parameter to gulp?

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Vortilion, 99.9% of the "Possible duplicate" (link above) is applicable to your question. However the `npm-run-all` dependency _may_ not be necessary for your requirement, Essentially you need to add double hyphens (`--`) at the end of your npm script, and utilize the nodejs builtin [`process.argv`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv) in your _gulpfile_ to read the args.